# Azure Web Service over SSL returns incorrect soap address location

Tags: wcf, azure, wcf-binding

I have a Cloud Service running over SSL on Azure; I can browse to the service and get its `wsdl` over SSL but when I do the `soap address location` is returned incorrectly - instead of using the domain name bound to the certificate I get the server name

> < soap:address location="http:// rd00155d45cc3c/Amazon.svc"/>

I am expecting to see

> < soap:address location="https://azure.mydomain.com/Amazon.svc"/>

My config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>                
            <binding name="AzureBinding">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="MyService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                      contract="StudentServiceWCF.IAmazon" 
                      bindingConfiguration="AzureBinding" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" 
                      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
               <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

My app.config client endpoint is configured

```
<endpoint address="https://azure.mydomain.com/Amazon.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IOutOfDateSecure"
          contract="AzureService.IAmazon" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAmazon" />

<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAmazon">
    <security mode="Transport" />
</binding>
```

I don't know how to affect the address location so it uses the domain name from my certificate. Because it's returning the http location the test client is throwing an exception:

> The HTTP service located at http:// rd00155d45cc3c/Amazon.svc is unavailable

Comment: have you installed [this hotfix](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB971842), also do you use the [UseRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress](http://zamd.net/2010/01/14/using-request-headers-for-metadata-address/) ?

Comment: Where would I install that hotfix, on my local development box? There's a concerning message on it > Please be aware this Hotfix has not gone through full Microsoft product regression testing nor has it been tested in combination with other Hotfixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress` as suggested by @astaykov got me some of the way to the solution however in order to be able to get the `wsdl` over https I needed to add

```
<protocolMapping>
    <add scheme="https" 
         binding="basicHttpBinding" 
         bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</protocolMapping>
```

to the `system.serviceModel` section in my configuration and this gives me the correct result in my `soap:address location` element in the generated wsdl from Azure.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="AzureBinding">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>                
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="MyService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                      contract="StudentServiceWCF.IAmazon" 
                      bindingConfiguration="AzureBinding" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" 
                      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
                    <defaultPorts>
                        <add scheme="https" port="443" />
                    </defaultPorts>
                </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <protocolMapping>
        <add scheme="https" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
             bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </protocolMapping>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Thanks; Not sure why more people haven't had this issue; 28/08/13 still not fixed by the hotfix.

Answer (score 1):

So, a bit oldish in the comment, but check [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/spazuretrainingcourse_azurefromsponpremusingjquery_topic2.aspx).

`step 6` describes what behavior to add (`UseRequestHeadersForMeatadataAddress`) and when was it introduced: KB981002- WCF: Hotfix rollup upodate. This shall solve your issues.

And the KB981001 is an official hotfix / update for Windows. It must be installed on both - your dev machine, and the Windows Azure Instances where you deploy your service. However, if you are not explicitly targeting an old [Guest OS (specific osVersion)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758710.aspx), that hotfix must be already installed.

Comment: Adding `UseRequestHeadersForMetaDataAddress`, with **both** http and https schemes enabled gets the domain name, but **only** for http. When I removed the scheme for http, to force SSL only the servername was used again instead of my domain name.